# why does printf() circumvents segmentation fail when using pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, printf, scanf

I've been testing out a coding manipulation of points in C, and I've experienced a weird phenomenon of which I cannot explain.

The following code simply instantiates four double variables and receives user input to fill them all.

the weird thing is the commented out line, when the line is not commented the code works as intended, yet when I comment it out there's a segmentation fail during the loop.

I've been coding this test on `c9.io`

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double i, a, b, c, d;
    double * cur = &a;
    char ch = 'a';
    // printf("a - %p\nb - %p\nc - %p\nd - %p\n",&a, &b, &c, &d);
    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        printf("Enter %c: ", ch++);
        scanf("%lf", cur++);
    }
    printf("a - %lf\nb - %lf\nc - %lf\nd - %lf\n",a, b, c, d);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm at a loss of words, why would the printing of the addresses circumvent the segmentation fail?

Comment: undefined behaviour really does mean "undefined"

Comment: @SouravGhosh I've re-edited the Title since that's not my question.

Comment: @GiladMitrani re-edited? where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35824496/4265352) already explains where is the problem in the code and how to fix it. I won't repeat it.

---

[Undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) doesn't mean the code works correctly or incorrectly, it means the behaviour cannot be predicted. And that means it can be different on different machines and even on consecutive runs on the same machine.

When you include the `printf()` line the code still has undefined behaviour. It looks like it is working properly but it is not.

In the particular case of your program the usage of address operator (`&`) with variables `b`, `c` and `d` in the `printf()` line forces the compiler to store them in memory. There are no rules that tells it how to place the variables in memory; most compilers place the variables in consecutive memory locations in the order they were defined. This is what probably happened here too. And this is why `cur++` probably advances to the address of `b` then `c` then `d` and the program apparently works correctly.

When the `printf()` line is commented out, the compiler probably optimizes the memory usage and chooses to store some of the variables `b`, `c` and `d` in registers. This way `cur++` cannot reach them. Because `a` is a local variable, on many architectures it is stored on the stack. `cur++` walks the stack and `scanf("%lf", curr++)` corrupts it by overwriting the function's return address and other values. When the function completes it returns to an invalid memory address. Kaboom! Segmentation fault.

Comment: this is the answer i've been looking for. thank you.

Answer (score 5):

In your code,

```
 double * cur = &a;
```

and then doing

```
 scanf("%lf", cur++);
```

does not point to `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` variables sequentially, as you might have expected. It is simply undefined behavior.

FWIW, attempt to access out of bound memory, invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In case, you want to keep the same approach, you can define `a` as an array (instead of separate variables like `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) and then you can use `cur` to *traverse* over the array. Array members are always contiguous.

Comment: I've tried out this test in order to not use arrays. have you a different approach?

Comment: @GiladMitrani There's no guarantee of the order of allocation of separate variables. Only the array members are guaranteed to be contiguous.

Comment: Okay its undefined, but I cannot help but wonder whether somewhere in the printf() stack of calls there's an explanation. Some forced segmentation of some kind.

Answer (score 2):

You are using scanf() to write values into `*cur`.  Since `cur` points to a stack variable, the most likely cause of your segfault is that the stack is not laid out the way you think and, as you increment the pointer, scanf() is overwriting something vital on the stack, such as the return address, or perhaps a stack frame pointer.  Both of those will easily lead to a segfault.

Edit: adding another idea I had in a comment below:

Another possibility is that incrementing `cur` actually causes it to go not from `&a` to `&b`, but the other direction, from `&a` to `&cur`. As mentioned, there is no guarantee of order on the stack. That would cause `scanf()` to corrupt `cur` itself. Adding the `printf()` may change the stack allocation in some way, since `a,b,c,d` are needed before the `printf()`, but `cur` is not used until after.

Comment: Oh, and as for why the printf() masks the segfault... it's just a matter of that varargs call changing the function's stack access patterns.

Comment: can you please expand upon that statement \ link me to a please i can read up on this?

Comment: That would depend a lot on architecture, but here's a quick link to wikipedia's page on x86 calling conventions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: I just had a thought...

Another possibility is that incrementing `cur` actually causes it to go not from `&a` to `&b`, but the other direction, from `&a` to `&cur`.  As mentioned, there is no guarantee of order on the stack.  That would cause `scanf()` to corrupt `cur` itself.

Adding the printf may change the stack allocation in some way, since a,b,c,d are needed before the printf, but cur is not used until after.